# How Does SnapChat Switch Between Tabs So Fast?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift4

I've done UIViewController switching before but how do you optimize for speed and light weight like Snapchat does?

Do they have One UIVIewController and the Received feed and News feed act as UIView and on click they just animate them over? Would they use story boards or all programmatically?

Also, as for general applications out there like Spotify, how do they make everything so lightweight and fast to switch views?

Note: Not looking for code, just a general overview summary on HOW they've would've done this. Example. (All View Controllers but they call it differently, UIViews?, A certain framework?)

Comment: Speed should only really be an issue on a simulator. On an actual device, everything should really be running pretty smooth. Do you get a delay when switching to a new controller or do you just find it slightly sluggish?

Comment: @DanielDramond Well its just not the same, when you do a push to a new view controller it still isn't as fast as lets say Spotify loading up the table views and such. Maybe its just the way I'm doing it, unless there is a "Correct" way for speed optimization

Comment: One thing that will be different in the likes of Snapchat is that they use custom transitions. If you're setting the animation to true when presenting or pushing a controller, it will use the default iOS transition - which isn't the quickest. You may want to look into writing and using a custom transition as you'll be able to have full control over how fast a controller is presented / dismissed

Comment: @DanielDramond That could be it! Also, is it better to make all the view controllers programatically or use story boards? Any speed difference or is one way preferred over the other when you're in the iOS Development world (as for jobs)

Comment: I personally don't use storyboards. The only speed issue you have when using storyboards is on the runtime (the time it takes to run on a device or simulator). Of course this run time is reduced when doing everything programmatically and yes, it looks really good on your CV (resume) as it proves that you're more than likely to know how to actually code. It definitely contributed to me getting my job as an iOS Dev.

Comment: @DanielDramond Ya I know what you mean, I currently have a job  as Laravel Developer and wanting to do iOS on the side. Picking up programatically wouldn't be too difficult, just the way it should be run /created / speed is what I am really looking into